# Pure strategy Nash equilibria

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I'm given a matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    (4,3)      & (5,1) & (6,2) \\
  (2,1)       & (8,4) & (3,6\\
   (3,0)      & (9,6) & (2,8) 
\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm supposed to find the pure strategy Nash equilibrium and Pareto efficiency in this game. I know how to approach when I need to find a mixed strategy using probability distributions, but I do not know how to approach this one. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the left elements from the pairs are the payoffs for player $1$, and the right the ones for player $2$, then you underline the optimal choice for player $i$ ($i=1,2$), given the choice of the other player. So for your example you would have

\begin{bmatrix}
    (\underline{4},\underline{3})      & (5,1) & (\underline{6},2) \\
  (2,1)       & (8,4) & (3,\underline{6})\\
   (3,0)      & (\underline{9},6) & (2,\underline{8}) 
\end{bmatrix}

The strategy $(1,1)$ yields a pure strategy Nash equilibrium, since the strategy $1$ is optimal for both players given the choice of the other. Can you see why this works in general for $2$ player games with a finite amount of choices?

Comment: I see. And as far as I can understand, there're no pareto efficient outcomes from this game?

Comment: There are several Pareto efficient outcomes for this game... Do you know the definition of Pareto efficiency?

Comment: Improve the score of one player without ruining the score of the other player. Since there's a (2, 8) outcome, wouldn't this mean that whenever player 1 chooses an outcome that has a <8 gain for the second player, he instantly ruins the second player's outcome?

Comment: There are $5$ Pareto efficient outcomes, can you see which ones? You have to look for outcomes for which we cannot increase the score of one player without strictly decreasing the other player's score. Consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency

Comment: I think I misunderstand the concept

Comment: Could you please explain on how you found 5? I still can't see any

Comment: Sorry I was too quick: there are only $2$ if you use the definition on Wikipedia. $(9,6)$ is a Pareto efficient state: we cannot make player $1$ better off, so surely we cannot make player $1$ beter of without decreasing the score of the other player. Next we cannot increase player $2$'s score without making $1$ worse off, because player $1$ is worse off in any other state that $(3,2)$

Comment: There's no (3,2) outcome, you mean (3, 0)?

Comment: You say you are given a matrix. Row $3$, column $2$.

Comment: I don't understand. For example (2, 8) is a state where we would increase second player's score but ruin first player's score. By definition, shouldn't this make (9,6) non-efficient pareto?

Comment: No. Please revisit the definition. "Pareto efficiency or Pareto optimality is a state of allocation of resources from which it is impossible to reallocate so as to make any one individual or preference criterion better off without making at least one individual or preference criterion worse off. "

Comment: Ooooh. I see the difference now. So that means (2, 8) is efficient since we can't further increase player 2's score thus we cannot make player 1 score's worse?

Comment: If I understand it correctly: if there are no 2 states that have the same maximum outcome for one of the players, than that state is pareto efficient?

Comment: For the first comment: you are right. For the second: I don't get what you are saying. Which state?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78161/discussion-between-vaclav-mordvinov-and-kjanko).